# Microsoft Exchange + moving contact record into another folder

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Exchange Noob here,

I need to move a contact information record to another folder from a c# application. 
I have no clue how to do that - anybody got pointers? Should I do remove and then re-add? That would be clunky.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I came to this link http://blog.mbcharbonneau.com/2006/10/26/using-net-and-webdav-to-access-an-exchange-server/ ...using WEBDAV - I just need the right request call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged you question with "exchangewebservices" I assume you are working with Exchange 2007 or 2010. You can use the Exchange WebServices or Exchange Managed API. With the Exchange Managed API you can use the Item.Move method to move the item to a different folder. If you want to use EWS directly, use the MoveItem operation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa564512(v=exchg.140).aspx).